# Close ie9 popup launched from iframe while Javascript processing (res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#,)

Tags: javascript, iframe, crash, popup, internet-explorer-9

I have done everything, but I CANNOT get ie9 to survive closing an application I am accessing in a popup window. I have reinstalled ie, I have all latest windows updates, I have updated JQuery to 1.9.1 from 1.6.4, I have tried forcing ie7, ie8 modes (taken out the 
"edge" setting, etc), ensured my launching app/parent window was set to the exact same version, I have reset ie settings, I have disabled all add-ons. Site works like a charm in Chrome (though Chrome sports a certain amount of suck too, for this, it works). I MUST use ie - no choice. (...out of desperation, I also updated Java as one thread I found, suggested). Additionally, both the launching application, and the popup application are being served off the same machine.

I have a parent application which, among other things, provides a menu from which I want to launch my other application. This other application loads a large amount of data into a fairly involved, robust, and quite functional gui. However, sometimes when I close 
the window, I get this error: res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#, Initially I suspected my AJAX loading... closing while loading etc.

It's not that. And the problem is not that the child window has an error...who cares, I'm closing it... my problem is that the parent ie window blows up.

I've isolated the problem - can make it happen every time, on command. If Javascript (in the child app) is processing - anything... and I close the window, *boom* the parent window breaks and tries to reload. (The menu I am launching the child app from *is* in an 
iframe..this *should not* matter, but I may have to accept some reality there)

I've cut everything back to one processing loop that works on and prepares the gui using a large amount of data returned. I've introduced intervals at a level such that only one command in the large routine executes at a time, giving the browser a chance to 
breath by increasing a PC, and setting another interval to go back around til things are done. I've done this with all routines prior to my "main" procedure as well.

I have a spinner, that obviously stops when the browser (ie9) is busy with Javascript (either native or via JQuery, doesn't seem to matter)...when the spinner pauses, and I close the window: boom, the parent crashes. (if I click close while the spinner is going, and the browser is breathing, the unload event gets fired, and everything closes OK.. though still not as smooth as Chrome, but..)

Thinking it was my AJAX loading, I tried clean-up routines on window closing. However, when it crashes, this never even gets fired.

I find it all very insane...dear ie, the window is closing...any perceived problems should be realized there, you should not blow up the parent. Again, Chrome handles the scenario without issue.

Running the browser on Windows 7.

EDIT:

---

I've moved on, but here's an example. This is being launched from an iframe with this command: window.open(url, '', 'width=1280,height=730,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,resizable=yes', '');

Close the window after the 'here...' alert. Boom.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Nunyabusiness.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />

<style type="text/css">


</style>

<script src="http://Nunyabusiness/Javascript/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://Nunyabusiness/Javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function doStuff() {

        // NOTE: I have included a while loop only for demonstration purposes. In my code I have 
        //       broken processing up in to very granular bits to let the browser breath, but the
        //       fact is, there is going to be *some* point where js is busy doing stuff...
        //       This loop just lets me blow it up, every time, without, err.. fail :|

        while (1) { // close the window, ie go boom

            // yes I can do this by setting an interval, and it prevents the crash, but that's not
            // a feasible solution... might as well write my own browser/scripting engine if this thing can *never* 
            // be busy...
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        alert('here...');

        doStuff();
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="divBusy">&nbsp;
</div>    

<div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ...crickets...tried a few more things. Moving common js code that launches app to iframe that does the launching. Tried loading popup app itself with an interval on the click... redesigned. Ditching the popup. I have control over both the launching app and the child app, so I can redesign the whole thing around an overlay/div/iframe, whatever.. that's my solution.

Comment: FYI: Also tried launching that loop outside the document ready func using an interval...same results.

Comment: FYI: I've also tried/ensured the click that launches this from the iframe. uses an interval as well.... so it's not nested anywhere. Sets a nav link url, then the func that is run (once) on an interval, loads the link with the above window.open(). Same result.